# Cloning git repository to the local machine in Ansible

Tags: git, ansible, virtual-machine, jinja2

I'm trying to `git clone` a repository from a server onto my local machine, and then copy only some files from this to the remote machine that I am using Ansible to configure. I have a task in my playbook to clone something from the git server (to my local machine):

```
- name: "clone thing from git"
  git: 
    repo: example.com/someRepo.git
    dest: "{{ local_home_dir }}/someRepo"
    clone: yes
    accept_hostkey: yes
    recursive: yes
    force: yes
    version: master
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I then have a copy task below this, to copy only a few relevant files over to my remote which I am using Ansible to configure.

When I run my playbook, I get this error:

```
TASK [clone thing from git] ************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host 
via ssh: bmacaig@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
```

My "remote" in this case is a VM that I am accessing on `127.0.0.1:2222`. The repo is private, but I have my own SSH key registered in git.

Things I've already tried:

- I created an SSH key on my remote, and added it to my Git account.
- I added my git servers public key to the remotes `known_hosts` file.
- I provided a path to a key in ansible, `key_file: "{{ local_home_dir }}/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: I should note that I have cloned this repository before, locally, on the same machine that I'm attempting to clone from now.

Comment: Looks like your own `localhost` that you cannot `ssh` to.  Try setting `connection: local` on the task.

Comment: @Jack I gave that a go, now it's throwing an error for "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required". My SSH key doesn't require a password (either locally or on my remote). Any thoughts?

Comment: You are using privilege escalation (i.e. `become: true`) and your user cannot sudo without a password. You have to provide it on the command line (`-K` to ask for it) or in your inventory (or remove privilege escalation from your playbook if you don't need it). And please refrain from diluting the needed info to answer your question in comments. Edit your question instead. Thanks.

Comment: Probably don't need privilege escalation anyway.  You can set `become: false` on the task.